# Use Hash with Redundant Items in sqlite3 Bind

Tags: ruby, sqlite3-ruby

I'm trying to run an INSERT query such as the following:

```
Query = "INSERT INTO t (x,y,z) VALUES (:aval,:bval,:cval)"
```

Using the following format, I can use a hash to insert the actual values:

```
db.execute(Query,{"aval" => "1", "bval" => "2", "cval" => "3"})
```

My problem is that the values are already in a hash that has some redundant values, e.g.:

```
{"aval" => "1", "bval" => "2", "cval" => "3", "dval" => "4"}
```

Since dval is not one of the required parameters, I get the error -

```
SQLite3::Exception: no such bind parameter
```

Of course, I may be wrong and the error may be due to a different reason.
It would be great if there were a way to overcome this using SQLite3. Alternatively, a method for creating a "trimmed" copy of the has with only the required parameters would also be OK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should write as -

```
Query = "INSERT INTO t (x,y,z) VALUES (?,?,?)"
hash = {"aval" => "1", "bval" => "2", "cval" => "3"}
db.execute(Query, hash.values_at("aval", "bval", "cval" ))
```

Read this [`execute( sql, *bind_vars ) {|row| ...}`](http://sqlite-ruby.rubyforge.org/classes/SQLite/Database.html#M000078) documentation.